# How to accomplish Facebook like home screen using Android API?

Tags: android

i am looking to add a home screen to my app sort of like facebook app has with little icons and labels under them (Pictures, Chat, Wall, etd). I would like to go this route as opposed to adding bunch of tabs on top.

My question is how i can get it done with Android API? I know i could probably make these icons with labels within but perhaps there is a way to make it in a native way.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular Button/ImageButtons, but with android:background="@null".  If you want the icons to change while they're being pressed or selected, use StateList Drawables.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: thanks i will check it out but can do a text label undel each element?

Comment: i was able to accomplish what i wanted with imagebuttons with @null background set so thanks for your help. i also used <TableLayout> and set 3 imagebuttons in one row with android:layout_weight or 33 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at the Facebook API and SDK for Android? They also provide functionality to create Facebook style dialogs aswell. Read-up more about the Facebook SDK [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile)

Comment: this app is not tied to Facebook, it's a stand alone app ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a RelativeLayout and defining the looks of the home screen in XML. I would use ImageButtons like mentioned by gngr44 and then make the text labels from TextViews. You can align them beneath the buttons in XML and RelativeLayout is probably best.

The Android Developers site has a lot of useful info to get started. Like this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: I dont quiet understand how i could get this to help me as i need at least 3 icons (with labels) per row. can you elaborate please?

Comment: Have you tried to test or read what Amplify suggested? Using a RelativeLayout you can do it. Have a look for `layout_below`, `layout_toRightOf` in RelativeLayout..